# Renaming an Asset in User Account on upload

Tags: craft3

I am using a miss match of what I have found across SE but I'm not really getting anywhere doing this form my module in Craft 3.

**What I would like to achieve:**
When a user uploads an asset to a custom field in their account, I'd like to rename that asset to be their company name (companyName custom field)

Any help/direction appreciated.

```
    Event::on(
        User::class,
        User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
        function (ModelEvent $event) {     
            
            //Set value of custom field
            $companyName = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->getFieldValue('companyName');
            $assetFileModels = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->getFieldValue('companyLogo');
            
            foreach ($assetFileModels as $assetFileModel)                
            {
                $newFileName = $companyName;
                Craft::$app->assets->moveAsset($assetFileModel, $assetFileModel->getFolder(), $newFileName);
                
            }
            
            
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following line will not return the expected result:

```
$companyName = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->getFieldValue('companyName');
```

Here's an updated version of your code that should work:

```
Event::on(
    User::class,
    User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
    function (ModelEvent $event) {     
        $user = $event->sender;
        
        // Get the company name and asset models from the user model
        $companyName = $user->companyName;
        $assetFileModels = $user->companyLogo;
        
        // Rename each asset file
        foreach ($assetFileModels as $assetFileModel) {                
            $newFileName = $companyName . '.' . $assetFileModel->getExtension();
            Craft::$app->assets->moveAsset($assetFileModel, $assetFileModel->getFolder(), $newFileName);
        }
    }
);
```